# Gcloud Cloud Armor for grpc web service in GKE - is there a working config?

Tags: kubernetes, grpc, google-cloud-armor

I have a grpc-based web service that runs in Google Kubernetes Engine, and I have had no luck applying Cloud Armor to it.
Currently, this web service is exposed via a Kubernetes service of type External load balancer, which is bound to an External TCP/UDP Network load balancer in Gcloud, and that all works fine.
The issue is that Cloud Armor cannot be applied to an External TCP/UDP Network load balancer.
So I've tried exposing the web service via Kubernetes services of type Node Port and Cluster IP to be able to bind to an Ingress that will use a load balancer that is supported for Cloud Armor (Global External HTTP(S), Global External HTTP(S) (classic), External TCP proxy, or External SSL proxy).
But I can't seem to find a configuration that actually handles the grpc traffic correctly and has a working healthcheck.
Has anyone else been able to get a grpc based web service running out of GKE protected with Cloud Armor?

More background:
The web service is Go-based, and has two features to facilitate Kubernetes healthchecks. First, it supports the standard grpc health protocol with grpc-health-probe, and the container that it is built into also has the grpc-health-probe executable (and this looks to be working correctly for the pod liveness/readiness checks). Second, it also serves an http(1) 200/OK on the '/' route on the same port on which it listens for the http/2 grpc traffic.
The web service runs with TLS using a CA-signed cert and a 4096 bit key, and currently terminates the TLS client traffic itself. But I am open to having the TLS traffic terminated at the edge/load balancer, if it can be made to work for grpc calls.

Answer (score 0):

The [Cloud Armor SSL TCP proxy](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/security-policy-overview#policy-types) is available, but there are some limitations:

Users can reuse existing Cloud Armor security policies (Backend security policies) or create new ones.

Only security policies with the following rule properties are are supported for TCP/SSL Proxies backend services:

- Match Conditions: IP, Geo, ASN
- Action: Allow, deny, throttle, rate-based-ban

Availability and limitations:

- Security policies can be created/configured in the Console or via API/CLI
- New or existing security policies can be attached to backend services fronted by TCP/SSL Proxies only via [API/CLI](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/backend-services/update).
- To enable Cloud Logging events, leverage CLI/API to enable TCP/SSL Proxy logging on the relevant backend service as described in the [Load Balancer documentation](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/https-logging-monitoring#gcloud:-global-mode)

There is a [Network Load Balancer](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/advanced-network-ddos) option that will be coming to market and is currently pre-GA.  It is expected to be generally available sometime in H1 2023.

Comment: Thank you Dave - I will try creating an SSL/TCP proxy load balancer and getting the Kubernetes Ingress to use that instead of the default HTTP(S) load balancer that it wants to create with an Ingress.